# Leaving CFSTR_FILECONTENTS/CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR entry in Clipboard when App terminates

Tags: mfc, ole

I've been using these clipboard formats to allow data to be pasted directly as a file from my app into Windows Explorer.

My implementation makes use of the MFC class COleDataSource but that's just a wrapper around IDataObject and APIs like OleSetClipboard .

When my app terminates my local implementation of IDataObject (i.e. a class derived from COleDataSource ) will have to go away so I call COleDataSource::FlushClipboard. This should put a copy of all the current data unto the clipboard (even delayed rendered content) so that is available after the app has closed down.

This works with simple formats like CF_TEXT but the CFSTR_FILECONTENTS format no longer works. Windows Explorer provides a Paste menu item but when I attempt to paste there's a standard MessageBeep sound and nothing happens.

Is it possible to get this to work or is CFSTR_FILECONTENTS dependent on the original IDataObject implementation still being active?

Comment: How are you setting the information in the dataobject. Are you delay rendering CFSTR_FILECONTENTS?

Answer (score 0):

Complex data is copied at the time you request it. If your source is dead, your data is gone.